# Get data into $scope from $http get from separate service file

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a problem with a service call. I want to put all get requests in a separate service file. It is working and I receive the data in my angular controller in the `.then` function. But I do not know how to get the data out of the function into my scope. `Console.log` in the function shows me the object. `Console.log` outside functions shows me the whole promise. How can I get it outside? What am i doing wrong?

My `Service.js`:

```
app.service('mamiService',  ['$http','toaster', '$q', '$filter', function( $http, toaster, $q, $filter) {
/GET THE EMAIL TEMPLATES
this.getTexts = function () {
return $http.get('includes/php/getMongoTexts.php')
            .then(function(response) {
            return response;
            });
};
}]);
```

My function in the controller:

```
var receivedData = mamiService.getTexts().then(function(response){
          var newData = response.data;
          console.log(newData);
          return newData;
          });
console.log(receivedData);
```

The `console(newData)` shows me the object with all the data. 
The `console(receivedData)` the whole promise object. I only want return the data into `$scope`.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just make sure to attach the data to $scope in the `.then`

```
mamiService.getTexts().then(function(response){
  $scope.receivedData = response.data;
  ...
```

Comment: U are right. I had this before already. I found now out, that my problem was, that it gets async loaded and the scope war not loaded yet. so my console shows undefined. So i have to do something when its loaded. then it works. thanks!